# Does mobile phones use TCP/IP?

Tags: ip, voip, tcp, mobile-broadband

Does mobile phones (any kind of mobile phone?) use TCP/IP over radio signals for internet? I would also like to know if they use VoIP for telephony? Please tell me what they use, I'm confused.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, mobile phones (mainly 3G/4G phones) use TCP/IP for transferring data (such as browsing the web, downloading apps, etc.)

As for the phone calls, those don't really use VoIP, but are more a function of the technology the carrier uses (Verizon uses CDMA (4G is LTE) and AT&T uses GSM).